# How is it possible to use the same data file directory and data file name for different Installers (media file name.exe)

Tags: installation, install4j

I have configured several installers (*.exe) for 32bit and 64bit and for different stages, each of them has its own data file directory and datafile name (*.dat). Is it possible to configure only one data file directory and datafile name (*.dat) which is used by all the different installers, because the redundant datafiles (*.dat) only contains the same libraries of the executable Java-application.

Answer (score 0):

No, as of 8.0, this is not supported by install4j. Each media files has its own set of files. For external data files, this file set is sliced into various .dat files that correspond to intersections of sets of installation components.  There is currently no analysis that extracts common .dat files from different media files and puts them into a common directory.